# Locale filter in conjunction with new datepicker localization

Tags: localization, datepicker

So in WordPress 4.6 they added the localization to the jQuery datepicker to be automatic. I am posting here first because I am not sure if this is actually a bug with WP or if I am doing something wrong.

If I set my language in the settings to French then the datepicker correctly gets localized and shows the months etc in French. However, for a demo page I want to show this off and don't want to have the entire site set to French but instead just a single page. Here is what I am using:

```
function change_language( $locale ) {
    if ( is_page( 156 ) ) {
        return 'fr_FR';
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'change_language' );
```

It is correctly changing the locale of the page but is not actually loading the datepicker localization based on that locale. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Is there some kind of timing issue here perhaps? Maybe I am using the wrong filter? Or is this possibly a WP bug?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully change the datepicker's strings to a different locale for a single page using the [`switch_to_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/) function introduced in [WordPress v4.7](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/07/user-admin-languages-and-locale-switching-in-4-7/).

`switch_to_locale()` will modify the global `$wp_locale` variable which is used by `wp_localize_jquery_ui_datepicker()`. Changing the locale with the `locale` filter alone does not overwrite `$wp_locale`.

```
/**
 * Use switch_to_locale() on a special page.
 * This needs to be done early.
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_change_language' );
function wpse_change_language( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_page( 156 ) ) {
        // This will change the global $wp_locale which
        // is used by wp_localize_jquery_ui_datepicker() for translations.
        switch_to_locale( 'fr_FR' );
    }   
}
```

Enqueue datepicker styles and scripts.

```
/**
 * Load jQuery datepicker scripts and styles.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_datepicker' );
function wpse_enqueue_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );

    // Using code.jquery.com for simplicity. Normally I'd use a local file.
    wp_register_style(
        'jquery-ui',
        'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );

    // A simple datepicker initialization script.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpse-datepicker',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/wpse-datepicker.js',
        [ 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ],
        false,
        true
    );
}
```

**wpse-datepicker.js**

```
/**
 * Attach a datepicker to our markup.
 */
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

**Shortcode** (for demo purposes)

```
/**
 * A simple shortcode used for adding the markup for
 * the datepicker.
 */
add_shortcode( 'wpse_datepicker', 'wpse_datepicker' );
function wpse_datepicker() {
    // Start buffering output.
    ob_start(); 

    // Add some debugging info:
    echo '<p>The locale is: ' . get_locale() . '</p>';
    ?>

    <div id="datepicker"></div>

    <?php
    // Return output generated up to this point.
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**Content of page with ID 156**

> ```
> Testing the datepicker:
>
> [wpse_datepicker]
>
> Test complete!
> ```

Also note that it is necessary to have the language files installed for whatever locale is being used. They can be automatically installed by selecting the appropriate language in the admin area under *Settings > General > Site Language*.

Comment: rather than hooking `locale`, and having to remove it to stop the infinite loop, i achieve the same by hooking `pre_get_posts`, since OPs usage was conditional to the page.

Comment: Thank you @hwl!!  I knew what I was doing was a little kludgy but hadn't quite pinned down the fix. This is much better.

Comment: all good! I was jumping on after testing the same approach and saw you had it down. i'll add this resource for that new (4.7) Wp_Locale_Switcher class, too:  (https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/07/user-admin-languages-and-locale-switching-in-4-7/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This worked for me. Any drawbacks to this approach I should be aware of?

Comment: Glad to hear, Nick! I just made a slight update, adding the `is_main_query()` check in `pre_get_posts()` (which I had initially forgotten, thanks @SarahCoding). I don't know of any drawbacks for the use case you've outlined. If you were going to do something using all languages, then it might be a good idea to download all languages preemptively which would address the performance hit that @SarahCoding  brought up).

Comment: Cool thanks for the reply. Yeah I always forget to check the main query too, good addition.

Answer (score 1):

Create `page-156.php` template with its content matching the page you use right now. Save it in your theme, where your standard page.php is located.

> Download `datepicker-fr.js` from
>   https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n and store it
>   in root of your site.

Replace inline script for *datepicker* widget with:

```
<script src="/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
  } );
</script>
```

That's all needed, for your demo page, to display *datepicker* in French.

Comment: Added downloaded French localization script. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress loads default translated strings before loading theme `functions.php` file ([see `wp-settings.php#L394`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L394)). Then, the `locale` filter doesn't affect the jQuery UI datepicker localization anymore.

There're some improvements I want to add to the answers of @DaveRomsey and @FrankPWalentynowicz:

**1. Using [`switch_to_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/)**:

This method works for a specific locale if that locale exists in available languages of the global `$wp_locale_switcher` (see [`WP_Locale_Switcher#L78`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-locale-switcher.php#L78)).

Since `WP_Locale_Switcher` uses [`get_available_languages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_available_languages/) to retrieve available languages, if `fr_FR` haven't been downloaded before, we have to download it into `WP_LANG_DIR` before switching to it:

```
function wpse268774_change_language($query) {
    if ( $query->is_page(156) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if (!function_exists('wp_download_language_pack')) {
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php';
            $downloaded = wp_download_language_pack('fr_FR');
            if ($downloaded) {
                switch_to_locale('fr_FR');
            } else {
                // Maybe do something...
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse268774_change_language' );
```

**Pros**:

- You can use standard translations for entire page without having to translate anything manually.

**Cons**:

- A heavy performance hit because we have to download language pack and reload entire translated strings.

I recommend you to use `pre_get_posts` hook with `$query->{method}`. `is_page()` alone may not works. You should not use page ID because it may be changed while importing.

**2. Using [`$.datepicker.setDefaults( options )`](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/datepicker/#utility-setDefaults)**:

WordPress doesn't use languages from [jQuery UI Project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n) so the `$.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional["fr"])` method doesn't work. You must localize default options manually.

Let's checkout [`wp_localize_jquery_ui_datepicker()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_jquery_ui_datepicker/) function added to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook (see [`default-filters.php#L435`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L435)). Now, we have to do:

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_localize_jquery_ui_datepicker', 1000);

function wpse268774_localize_jquery_ui_datepciker() {
    global $wp_locale;

    if ( !is_page(156) || !wp_script_is( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Convert the PHP date format into jQuery UI's format.
    $datepicker_date_format = str_replace(
        array(
            'd', 'j', 'l', 'z', // Day.
            'F', 'M', 'n', 'm', // Month.
            'Y', 'y'            // Year.
        ),
        array(
            'dd', 'd', 'DD', 'o',
            'MM', 'M', 'm', 'mm',
            'yy', 'y'
        ),
        get_option( 'date_format' )
    );

    // Got this string by switching to fr_FR.
    $datepicker_defaults = '{"closeText":"Fermer","currentText":"Aujourd\u2019hui","monthNames":["janvier","f\u00e9vrier","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","ao\u00fbt","septembre","octobre","novembre","d\u00e9cembre"],"monthNamesShort":["Jan","F\u00e9v","Mar","Avr","Mai","Juin","Juil","Ao\u00fbt","Sep","Oct","Nov","D\u00e9c"],"nextText":"Suivant","prevText":"Pr\u00e9c\u00e9dent","dayNames":["dimanche","lundi","mardi","mercredi","jeudi","vendredi","samedi"],"dayNamesShort":["dim","lun","mar","mer","jeu","ven","sam"],"dayNamesMin":["D","L","M","M","J","V","S"],"dateFormat":"MM d, yy","firstDay":1,"isRTL":false}';

    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', "jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({$datepicker_defaults});});" );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse268774_localize_jquery_ui_datepciker', 10, 0);
```

**Pros**:

- No performance hit

**Cons**:

- Only localize jQuery UI Datepicker options. Other strings in your page won't be translated.
- You may have to translate the jQuery UI Datepicker options manually.